# Custom Post Types - Current section heading above the loop?

Tags: custom-post-types

On the site I am currently developing I have used custom post types for the different types of content it contains (News, Podcasts, Press Releases etc). How would I go about showing the label (plus a bit of text) for each section above the loop?

For example:

**Press Releases**

Some text under the heading.

- Press Release 1
- Press Release 2
- Press Release 3
- Press Release 4
- Press Release 5

Any idea how I would go about achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the template page in question is the archive index for the custom post type, you can simply create a custom template file, `archive-{post-type}.php`, and add in the Title and custom text.

If you don't want to create a custom template file, you can use this boolean as a conditional in your existing `archive.php` template file, for creating custom output:

```
<?php is_post_type_archive( $post_types ); ?>
```

To retrieve the Title for a Post Type archive:

```
<?php post_type_archive_title( $prefix, $display ); ?>
```

To retrieve the current Post Type (for use in PHP):

```
<?php get_post_type( $post ) ?>
```

To retrieve all Post Type information (e.g. to output Title, Description, etc. if configured):

```
<?php get_post_type_object(); ?>
```